# How to integrate Laravel-Mongodb with Yajra-Laravel-Datatables?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, yajra-datatable

I have successfully integrated Laravel v9+ and Mongodb with help of this package https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb . I tried integrating https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables , and i am getting errors. I have followed yajra documentation to integrate it with Laravel. Has anyone else faced errors?
I faced errors given below:

1. "Call to a member function prepare() on null" in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
2. Exception Message: $meta is the only expression supported by $sort right now.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: or use this plugin (1s google search "mongodb eloquent datatables") https://github.com/pimlie/laravel-datatables-mongodb

Comment: this does not work i already tried it.